# Unit Testing Model property binding in Angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Angular 5 with Jasmine to perform Unit Testing.

I have a model called PlayerAccount array that looks like the following:

```
export interface IPlayerAccount {
  playerId: number;
  name: string;
  phone: number;
  street: string;
  postcode: string;
  state: string;
  country: string;
}
```

This PlayerAccount array gets populated on ngOnInit by calling method

```
getPlayerAccounts(playerId: number);
```

I'm trying to unit test that the returned PlayerAccount data successfully binds to the PlayerAccount array.

I have got this far but I feel like my approach is a little hacky, so I’m wondering if there is a nicer way to bind the returned data from getPlayerAccounts to my array of IPlayerAccount

```
 it('check that array of players successfully bind to component accounts players array', async () => {
          fixture.detectChanges();

          IPlayerAccount accounts = new IPlayerAccount();

          var account1 = new IPlayerAccount();
          account1.playerId = 1;
          account1.name = 'Ben';
          account1.phone = 12345;
          account1.street = 'Cloud Street';
          account1.postcode = 111;
          account1.state = 'MELB'
          account1.country = 'AU';

          var account2 = new IPlayerAccount();
          account2.playerId = 2;
          account2.name = 'James';
          account2.phone = 6789;
          account2.street = 'Jamming Street';
          account2.postcode = 2323;
          account2.state = 'VIC'
          account2.country = 'AU';

          component.accounts.push(account1);
          component.accounts.push(account2);

          IPlayerAccount[] returnedAccounts = component.getMerchantAccounts(1);

          expect(component.accounts[0]).toEqual(returnedAccounts[0]);
          expect(component.accounts[1]).toEqual(returnedAccounts[1]);

        });
```

Can someone please help me write this unit test? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what output you get from the failing test? Is there an error, or does one of your `expect`s fail?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave this is more of a conceptual question about my approach to solving this problem rather than fixing my error - I think my approach needs to be changed. Do you have an alternative solution in mind?

Comment: Not really, without knowing what the actual problem is (i.e. what "fail" means in this case) it's hard to think about what solutions might work.

Comment: Basically I am trying to test that the json data returned from the components call to getPlayerAccounts successfully binds to my array of IPlayerAccount @DaveyDaveDave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Testing Model Binding in Angular 5 with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295168/unit-testing-model-binding-in-angular-5-with-jasmine)